# Magick++ can't read raw nef image

Tags: c++, ubuntu, imagemagick

I am trying to read a raw image using magick++.  According to this list the nikon's NEF format should be supported by image magick.  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Here is my code...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
    Magick::Image im;
    im.read("/home/chase/Desktop/DSC_0985.NEF");

    im.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message...

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorBlob'
  what():  Stacking: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-25923_ETdn5fNSJR5.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709
```

I installed magick++ using `sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev`.  I am using ubuntu 15.04

I just tried this as well.  Same error.  NEF should be supported.

```
Magick::CoderInfo c("NEF");
if(c.isReadable())
{
    Magick::Image im;
    im.read("/home/chase/Desktop/DSC_0985.NEF");

    im.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Ubuntu, but on OS X at least, ImageMagick uses `ufraw` and `ufraw-batch` for `NEF`, `DNG` and `CR[2W]` raw files, so I would suggest you try installing those, presumably with something like:

```
apt-get install ufraw
apt-get install ufraw-batch
```

Comment: That worked really well.  Thanks!  I am surprised that was not a dependency when I installed image magic.

Comment: I guess ImageMagick does not *require* you to install packages you may not need - they are kind of *"optional add-ons"* that you add on if you need. Maybe someone else knows and can explain better. Anyway, glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageMagick` not read directly RAW
they use `dcraw` for convert to `.ppm` and them open it.

Try install `dcraw`.

Comment: Then why was it listed on that list.  Also is there a way for it to automatically read the images if I install dcraw?

Comment: I look it process under Windows, Imagemagick run dcraw.exe process automatically. Install of Imagemagick  under windows have dcraw.exe in same directory.
p.s. in our project we use `libraw` for direct reading raw, and them build ImageMagick from blob.

Comment: I kind of wanted a solution which supports raw as well as normal images.